# How to transform and save dataframe to csv python

Tags: python, screen-scraping

Is there a way to transform and then save following dataframe to a csv file like this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ev-database.uk'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

urls = []
cars = []
for h in soup.find_all('h2'):
    a = h.find('a')
    cars.append(a.attrs['href'][10:])
    urls.append(a.attrs['href'])

import requests 
import pandas as pd

list_length = len(urls)
table = pd.DataFrame()

for x in range(5):
    page_link ='https://ev-database.uk' + urls[x]

    for i in range(1,3):
        next_table = pd.read_html(requests.get(page_link).content)[i]
        next_table[3] = cars[x]
        table = table.append(next_table, ignore_index = True)
```

Dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

`csv.output`:

[image: csv.output]

Comment: Hi David, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please edit your question to include the actual text of your code / tables, instead of photos?  Also, please edit this to be a [minimum verifiable, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Additionally, it would be good if you explained what you've tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

Use,

```
table.set_index([3,0])[1].unstack().rename_axis([None]).to_csv('csv.output')
```

Output:

```
                            Annual VED Annual VED * City - Cold Weather City - Cold Weather *  \
Audi-e-tron-Quattro                None         £310                None                260 mi   
Hyundai-Kona-Electric-64-kWh         £0         None              240 mi                  None   
Jaguar-I-Pace                      £310         None              250 mi                  None   
Nissan-Leaf                          £0         None              145 mi                  None   
Tesla-Model-3                        £0         None                None                195 mi
```